# Android: Stopping Cursor from retrieving empty playlists and genres

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am currently using a `CursorAdapter` in conjunction with a `LoaderCusor` in order to retrieve all songs, playlists, albums, artists and genres from my device.

Everything is working fine except from my genre and playlists `Cursor`'s. The problem is that the cursor is retrieving both genres and playlists that are completely empty. Now in order to resolve this I attempted the following:

```
final String[] columns = 
            {
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,                   
            };            

        String where = BaseColumns._COUNT + "!=?";
        String[] whereVal = {0+""};                        

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                columns, 
                where, 
                whereVal,
                null);
```

and similarly for playlists. However this constantly throws an error telling me that the _count column does not exist for neither the playlists nor the genres. I also that the error if I try and use `MediaStore.Audio.Genres._COUNT`.

With this in mind, is there any way to prevent the `CursorLoader` from retrieving empty playlists and genres? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. 

The column isn't listed in the docs either. I think it's safe to assume it doesn't exist.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.GenresColumns.html

Comment: Did you get any further on this topic?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've temporarily stopped working on this app but I am still very interested to find a solution.